# How do I move a graphics.Rectangle with my Keys?

Tags: c#, graphics

I'm quite simply trying to move my rectangle that I have drawn from the graphics class, up and down according to the keys pressed. However, I have no idea how to move a graphics object, but only primarily form components.

This is my code so far, but I am not sure how I should be doing this.

```
private Graphics paddle1;

    public void Move(Keys key)
    {
        switch (key)
        {
            case Keys.W:
                paddle1.Top -= 20;
                break;
        }
    }
```

I have assigned my graphics object to the name 'paddle1' and I cannot simply use .Top to get the position of the graphics rectangle.

Is there another way of doing this?

EDIT:

I'm drawing the rectangle in a different method:

```
    public void Draw()
    {
        paddle1.FillRectangle(brush, position.X, position.Y, 20, 100);
    }
```

I'm using a controller class to draw the paddle, and then move it. The variable Key 'key' is unrecognized for some reason?

```
    public void Run()
    {
        paddle1.Move(Keys key); //This is unrecognized from my paddle class.
        paddle1.Draw();
```

Comment: Note that Graphics doesn't __contain__ any graphics, it is a __tool__ used to draw onto an associated Bitmap or a control's surface..  So you need to change the coordinates and then trigger the Paint event that does the drawing by calling Invalidate on the control you draw on..

Answer (score 0):

Here is some sample code, that allows you to move a rectangle by using the arrow keys. Currently it misses some boundary checks, but it should give you a good starting point.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Rectangle _SelectedArea;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _SelectedArea = new Rectangle(0, 0, 20, 20);
    }

    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyDown(e);

        if (!e.Handled)
        {
            switch (e.KeyData)
            {
                case Keys.Down:
                    _SelectedArea.Offset(0, 1);
                    break;

                case Keys.Up:
                    _SelectedArea.Offset(0, -1);
                    break;

                case Keys.Left:
                    _SelectedArea.Offset(-1, 0);
                    break;

                case Keys.Right:
                    _SelectedArea.Offset(1, 0);
                    break;
            }

            e.Handled = true;
            // The Invalidate() call causes the control to be redrawn.
            // Check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/598t492a.aspx
            Invalidate();
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        using (var pen = new Pen(Color.Red))
        using (var brush = new HatchBrush(HatchStyle.Percent10, Color.Blue, Color.Transparent))
        {
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, _SelectedArea);
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, _SelectedArea);
        }
    }
}
```